# Pascaline triangle logic not working in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program to print the Pascaline triangle. But it is not working properly. The code is provided below :

```
 int rows=10;
 int[] array=new int[10], temp=new int[10];
 array[0]=1;
 temp[0]=1;
 System.out.println(1);
 for(int i=1;i<rows;i++)
 {
     for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
     {
         temp[j]=array[j-1]+array[j];
     }
     for(int term:temp)
     {
         System.out.print(term+"\t");
     }
     System.out.println();
     array=temp;
 }
```

It is giving the following output :
1
1  1
1  2  3
1  3  5  5
.....
Please tell what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascaline triangle is not factorial serial

A proposal is (warning I am not a Java programmer, please don't be rude with me if something is stupid / can be improved easily) :

```
public class Pascaline {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int n = 10, i, j;
     int [] f = new int[n];

     f[0] = 1;

     for (i = 1; i != n; i++)
       f[i] = f[i - 1] * i;

     for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
         System.out.print((f[i] / (f[i - j] * f[j])) + " ");
       System.out.println();
     }
   }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ javac Pascaline.java 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ java Pascaline 
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
1 5 10 10 5 1 
1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

and to be a little prettier :

```
public class Pascaline {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     int n = 10, i, j;
     int [] f = new int[n];

     f[0] = 1;

     for (i = 1; i != n; i++)
       f[i] = f[i - 1] * i;

     for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < n-i; j++)
         System.out.print(" ");
       for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
         System.out.print((f[i] / (f[i - j] * f[j])) + " ");
       System.out.println();
     }
   }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ javac Pascaline.java 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ java Pascaline 
           1 
          1 1 
         1 2 1 
        1 3 3 1 
       1 4 6 4 1 
      1 5 10 10 5 1 
     1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
    1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 
   1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 
  1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```